# CRC or SHA a directory and all sub directories and be able to check the hash later

Tags: cross-platform, ntfs

I need a program that will allow me to selected a directory, it will then go through that directory and all sub directories and create a crc list. That list will get saved. If I do another scan of that directory, it will only update changes while keeping the original values for files that haven't changed. Later if I want to verify all the files I can use the generated file to check all the files in it's list and it will output all the bad crc's, missing files, and new files it hasn't indexed.

I want to use this on backup drives as a safety net to make sure my backups are still good. I'm using NTFS and EXT4 as my backups. I know it can't fix the files, I'm only concerned that the files may go bad.

A cross platform tool would be ideal as the bulk of my backups are on an Ubuntu 18.04 system. It's kind of what SnapRaid does, only no recovery (parity) record.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on reddit and got a response.

https://github.com/trapexit/scorch

Scorch is a program that does all that I require. It is a Python 3 script and runs on Windows through the Windows Subsystem for Linux.